# Bootstrap dropdown not working after deploying to azure webapps

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, azure-web-app-service

I have an application which uses bootstrap. It works fine when I run it locally, but when I publish it to azure webapps, the dropdown is not working.

It throws the below error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Here is the code

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new object { }, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Master Data</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
            @Html.ActionLink("Trip Types", "Index", "TripTypes", new object { }, new { @class = "dropdown-item" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Activites", "Index", "Activites", new object { }, new { @class = "dropdown-item" })
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        @Html.ActionLink("Parameters", "Index", "Parameters", new object { }, new { @class = "nav-link" })
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are there any issues in the Console? Looks like there's an issue in your JavaScript. Might be because of the order in which you reference libraries, or in a bundle that breaks JS?

Comment: not sure what the issue is, but when I changed the configuration from release to debug it worked fine

Comment: Then there's probably an issue minifying your javascript. Try referencing them from a CDN.

Comment: downvoters, please care to drop a comment on what should be improved

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of bundling in MVC and I used the below code to turn off bundling

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

I added this line in the end of `BundleConfig.cs` in `App_Start` folder